# min and max date jquery datepicker in table with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

In my page I have table with Add, Edit and Delete operation. one of the  column in the table is Audit Date. The limitation on the date is that the date value can be anywhere from 10 minutes back to a day before the form in being filled.

When I am adding the min and max date limitation outside table it works fine
but the minute I add it in table it does not work

```
Date Outside Table (Works Perfectly)
<input type="text" datepicker="" ng-model="auditDate" id="AddAudit" /> 

$("#AddAudit").datepicker({
    maxDate: '-1',
    minDate: '-10M'
});


Date in Table  (does not work :-( )
<table ng-repeat="i in list">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" datepicker="" ng-model="i.startDate" ng-change="dateChanged(i)" id="EditAuditDate_{{i.id}}" />
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

$scope.dateChanged = function(item) {
var inpAuditDate = "#EditAuditDate_" + item.id;
    $(inpAuditDate).datepicker({
        maxDate: '-1',
        minDate: '-10M'
    });
};
```

[I have created an example to show the issue](http://jsbin.com/rasetoreci/edit?html,js,output)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You didn't use `min` or `minDate` options in your directive. Also using an ancient version of angular in the demo. Hopefully you are using a much more current version than that in your own code

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean by You didn't use min or minDate options in your directive. can you please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your min/max options to your *directive* code instead of loading the *datepicker* plugin from multiple places. You end up cleaning your controller and keeping the selection logic in the directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.list = [{
            id: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2
        },
        {
            id: 3
        }];
});

app.directive('datepicker', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
      $(el).datepicker({
        maxDate: '-1',
        minDate: '-10M',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Working [sample](http://jsbin.com/zeranidiqa/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: I don't want to do that as the directive is being used my many page in the application. I have a utility js that has all the directive. So any change has to be on the page